# Is there JS libraries for multisig/threshold sign on solana?

Tags: javascript, multisig

I've searched a lot, but I didn't find any JS libraries that would allow me to manage tss signatures/multisigs on Solana.

Comment: What's your use case? web3.js let's you partially sign transactions out-of-the-box: https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html#partialSign

Answer (score 2):

There is no *generic* MS/TS support on solana.  SPL Token specifies its own M:N MS, which the `@solana/spl-token` package supports.  Outside that, you'd need to focus the question on a specific MS/TS protocol

Answer (score 2):

The `coral-xyz/multisig` program is meant to provide a generic multisig, including JS / TS support.  You can find the program code at https://github.com/coral-xyz/multisig, note that it is unaudited, however.

There is also a test showing how to use the bindings at https://github.com/coral-xyz/multisig/blob/master/tests/multisig.js, ie:

```
    await program.rpc.approve({
      accounts: {
        multisig: multisig.publicKey,
        transaction: transaction.publicKey,
        owner: owner.publicKey,
      },
      signers: [owner],
    });

    await program.rpc.executeTransaction({
      accounts: {
        multisig: multisig.publicKey,
        multisigSigner,
        transaction: transaction.publicKey,
      },
      remainingAccounts: program.instruction.setOwners
        .accounts({
          multisig: multisig.publicKey,
          multisigSigner,
        })
        // Change the signer status on the vendor signer since it's signed by the program, not the client.
        .map((meta) =>
          meta.pubkey.equals(multisigSigner)
            ? { ...meta, isSigner: false }
            : meta
        )
        .concat({
          pubkey: program.programId,
          isWritable: false,
          isSigner: false,
        }),
    });
```